# Delete data sith Breeze.js without loading it to client

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I am using `Breeze.js` with `Entity Framework WebAPI` backend, and I need to delete a large set of data that is not loaded to client. I would really like to do it on the server and not load it.

Is there a "breeze way"? By that I mean a method in a `BreezeController`.

**EDIT**

I have to delete all rows from one table that belong to the user, whose date field is in future, and all their child rows.

Comment: Are we talking about having a Parent deleted and then you need to automatically delete all children? Or are we talking about you having lots of IDs or some other unique property and you just want to delete that - of course all from same table? Or something else? need more info.

Answer (score 1):

```
public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (
            var entry in
                this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                    .Where((e => (e.State == (EntityState) Breeze.WebApi.EntityState.Deleted))))
        {
            if (entry.Entity.GetType() == typeof(User))
            {
                var entity = entry.Entity as User;
                var childEntitiesInFuture = ChildEntities.Where(c => c.DateField > DateTime.Now);
                foreach (var child in childEntitiesInFuture){
                  var grandchildrenForDeletion = Grandchildren.Where(c => c.ChildId == child.Id);
                  foreach (var g in grandchildrenForDeletion) Grandchildren.Remove(g);
                  ChildEntities.Remove(child);
                }
             }
         }
    }
```

Assuming you are deleting `User`, one `User` has many `ChildEntity` saved in `ChildEntities` and each `ChildEntity` has many `Grandchild` saved in `Grandchildren`. A bit messy names, but that's what you get with no real names :)

This method goes into your Context class. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it will be of much use later, but it is not what I need. I am sorry for being unclear, I'll try to be more precise.

Every user has a set of, lets call them schedules. And I need to implement a "delete all future schedules" feature. The user is not getting deleted. Also, deleting the children is not a problem, they will cascade on delete. The problem is that I don't want to load the schedules to client, so I can't really delete them by using `saveChanges()`. Thanks again.

Comment: Cascade on delete is not yet implemented in breeze as far as I know. Breeze methods are all GET except for SaveChanges which is POST. Deleting should be in POST so I can recommend writing your own ajax call that sends info you need to identify what you need to delete, make a POST method which receives that data, and then delete data in that method. Make sure you force reloading data from server after that. Good luck.

Comment: I was afraid I would have to do something like that. Thanks for clearing that up. As for cascade, I specified it context definition.